Does Lamentations reference Hosea as source material?
Reading through Hosea after being deep in Lamentations, it seems that Lamentations (approximately exilic) references several motifs or tropes from Hosea (earlier, pre-exilic).
Does anyone know of any studies on this possibility? The collection "Reading Lamentations Intertextually" (2021, H.A.Thomas and B.N.Melton), t&t.clark), while covering many intertextual links, seems not to cover this one.

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I also recommend going through the Help Center's sections on both asking and answering questions.
